# Python 3: List index out of range

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Every time I run this command, I can't get through all of the cards without having this error; `IndexError`: list index out of range.

```
import random

cards = ['2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '8', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '9', '10', ',10', '10', '10', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']

randomness = 51

while True:

    cardIndex = random.randint(0, randomness)
    del cards[cardIndex]
    randomness = randomness -1
    print(cards[cardIndex])
```

Comment: so basically shuffle a deck of cards? plus you have `...,',10',...` in there, so one of your 10s isn't a ten, it's "comma ten".

Comment: Yes, I would like to shuffle a deck of cards and distribute every single cards. The comma doesn't change anything...

Comment: to print card in random order: `random.shuffle(cards); print("\n".join(cards))`

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 3):

Print `cards[cardIndex]` *before* deleting by that index:

```
while cards: # Because we need to stop somewhere
    cardIndex = random.randint(0, randomness)
    print(cards[cardIndex])
    del cards[cardIndex]
    randomness = randomness -1
```

And you don't need `randomness` at all:

```
while cards:
    cardIndex = random.randrange(len(cards))
    print(cards[cardIndex])
    del cards[cardIndex]
```

---

You'd do that using either [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
for c in random.sample(cards, len(cards)):
    print(c)
```

or [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) (which will modify the `cards` list):

```
random.shuffle(cards)
for c in cards:
    print(c)
```

Comment: there's also random.shuffle(seq) which randomly shuffles them all in place. [it even makes it sound like a deck of cards!]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you first delete the card and then print it, so the problem is when you pick the last card:

```
randomness = 51

while True:

    cardIndex = random.randint(0, randomness) #random.randint(0, 51) could give num 51 so card 52
    del cards[cardIndex] # deleted 52nd card (num 51)
    randomness = randomness -1
    print(cards[cardIndex]) # there is no 52nd card (num 51) anymore
```

what you want is to change printing and deleting:

```
while len(cards) > 0: # once yours pack of card is empty you want to stop
    cardIndex = random.randint(0, randomness)
    print(cards[cardIndex])
    del cards[cardIndex]
    randomness = randomness -1
```

[len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) tell you how many things are in list
It should work now :)

Comment: Thanks! You found what was wrong with my script!! It works perfectly now and the way you explained it to me really made me understand why this bug happened!

Answer (score -1):

```
while cards:
    idx = random.randint(0, len(cards) - 1)
    print(cards[idx])
    del cards[idx]
```

Comment: I changed what you told me to change but the bug appears before all the ''cards'' are distribute.